# Não consigo fazer esse programa funcionar. Sempre diz que os números são divisíveis

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "funcao.h"

int main () {
    int a, b;
    printf("Escreva os valores de a e b   ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);

    if (EDivisivel (a,b))
        printf("sao divisiveis");
    else
        printf("nao sao divisiveis");
        return (0);
}
```

/* a função está aqui em baixo: */

```
#include <stdio.h>
int EDivisivel (int a, int b) {
    if (a%b)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

A partir disso, nunca consigo resultados certos de números não divisíveis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para um número ser considerado divisível por outro o **resto da divisão (%)** entre eles tem que ser igual a 0. Ex: 6 / 3 = 2 e resto = 0.

Quando você faz `if (a%b)`, essa condição será verdadeira se o resto da divisão for igual a 1. Pois 1 -> True e 0 -> False.

Então, o correto seria verificar assim: `if (a%b == 0)`.

Comment: Brigadasso! Deu certo aqui já! Valeu mesmo